# How do I refer a table with custom numbering?

Tags: tables, macros, cross-referencing

I have the following code that generates a table:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\name}[4]{
    \begin{table}[!htbp]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{p{\textwidth}}
            \toprule
            \textbf{#1} \hspace{1em} #2    \\ \midrule
            #3 \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \label{name:#1}
    \end{table}
    \vspace{-1.25em}
    \paragraph{Justification:} #4 \\
}
\begin{document}
\name{AB:CDE:000}{XXX}{YYY}{ZZZ}

Some text \ref{name:AB:CDE:000}

\end{document}
```

Now every time I need to refer this, I need the reference to be seen as 'Name - AB:CDE:000'.
How do I achieve that?

Is it also possible to auto number it as AB:CDE:000, AB:CDE:010, AB:CDE:020 etc??

Comment: What is your minimal working example? Please not put snippet code.

Comment: @Sebastiano I edited the question accordingly. Thanks for informing that

Comment: Off-topic: `\begin{tabular}{p{\textwidth}}` *guarantees* that the width of the `tabular` environment will exceed `\textwidth` -- by `2\tabcolsep`, to be exact. To keep this from happening, you need to run either `\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}` or `\begin{tabular}{p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}`. A separate comment: the `\centering` instruction accomplishes nothing and might as well be omitted.

Comment: @Mico oh that's interesting! thanks for that, what does `@{}` do here?
and yea, `\centering` is useless here. I missed that!

Comment: The `@{}` particles suppress the whitespace padding that would otherwise get inserted.

Comment: ah yea, i see the difference now! grand! thanks!!
could you provide me any help with the posted question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not using a `\caption` directive with this table, there's no  numbered caption, and you can't use the `\label`-`\ref` mechanism to create a cross-reference.

For a different way to create cross-references, I suggest you load the `hyperref` package and employ its `\hypertarget`-`\hyperlink` mechanism. Note that the first argument of `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` directives must be same.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\newcommand{\name}[4]{
    \begin{table}[!htbp]
    \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}
    \toprule
    \smash{\hypertarget{#1}{\textbf{#1}}} \qquad #2 \\ 
    \midrule
    #3 \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \vspace{-5ex}
    \paragraph{Justification:}#4\par
}
\begin{document}
\name{AB:CDE:000}{XXX}{YYY}{ZZZ}

\bigskip\noindent
A cross-reference to table \hyperlink{AB:CDE:000}{AB:CDE:000}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked.